# (Python) How to convert my code to python 3 from 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a basic website crawler, in Python. However, the code that I've gathered from this website [here](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/news/basic-website-crawler-python-12-lines-code-0132785/) is for python 2.7. I'm wondering how I can code this for python 3 or greater. I've began to try and convert it, but I keep running into errors.

```
import re
import urllib

textfile = open('depth_1.txt', 'wt')
print("Enter the URL you wish to crawl..")
print('Usage  - "http://phocks.org/stumble/creepy/" <-- With the double quotes')
myurl = input("@> ")
for i in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.urlopen(myurl).read(), re.I):
    print(i)
    for ee in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.urlopen(i).read(), re.I):
        print(ee)
        textfile.write(ee+'\n')
textfile.close()
```

Comment: `2to3` comes with Python 2. `2to3 your_code_2.py`

Answer (score 2):

## Prepare your Python2 code

Say `2.py`

```
import re
import urllib

textfile = open('depth_1.txt', 'wt')
print("Enter the URL you wish to crawl..")
print('Usage  - "http://phocks.org/stumble/creepy/" <-- With the double quotes')
myurl = input("@> ")
for i in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.urlopen(myurl).read(), re.I):
    print(i)
    for ee in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.urlopen(i).read(), re.I):
        print(ee)
        textfile.write(ee+'\n')
textfile.close()
```

## Convert it with `2to3`

```
2to3 -w 2.py
```

## Now look into the directory with `dir` or `ls`

```
> dir
2016-09-24  01:53               533 2.py
2016-09-24  01:51               475 2.py.bak
```

`2.py.bak` is your original code and `2.py` is Python 3 code.

### See what changes have been made

```
import re
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

textfile = open('depth_1.txt', 'wt')
print("Enter the URL you wish to crawl..")
print('Usage  - "http://phocks.org/stumble/creepy/" <-- With the double quotes')
myurl = eval(input("@> "))
for i in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.request.urlopen(myurl).read(), re.I):
    print(i)
    for ee in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.request.urlopen(i).read(), re.I):
        print(ee)
        textfile.write(ee+'\n')
textfile.close()
```

**This works if you are using only built-ins and standard modules.** In your case, it's ok.

Comment: Py3.5 still has issues with the regex working on a bytes-like object. `.decode('utf-8')` on the response makes it work but not sure this is the best solution.